# fullcalendar - dynamically change row height

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I am trying to dymanically change row height of fullcalendar.

---

**Done so far.**

I added a slider in order to select row height.
With a little of jQuery I modify the css of the rows in order to make them wider or thinner.

The HTML code:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

and the associated javascript:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
      value:100,
      min: 20,
      max: 80,
      step: 20,
      value: 20,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        heightmod(ui.value);

      }
    });
    heightmod( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );

  });

  function heightmod(value)
  {
      $('.fc-time-grid .fc-slats td').css('height', value+'px');
  }

</script>
```

**Result:**

The height of the rows is updated properly, however ***the position of the inserted events and backgrounds does not change accordingly***.

Funny thing is, if I open or close the browser debug toolbar (**`ctrl+shift+i`** in most browsers) ***the html coordinates of the events inserted in the calendar is magically updated to match correct position***.

Has anyone had the same problem? Any suggestion?

Comment: I think the events react to the browser resize event. Maybe you can trigger this yourself? `$(window).trigger('resize');`

Comment: Post your comment as an answer A1rPun, because this is the right one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The events positions react to the browser resize event. You can resize the browser manually by calling:

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, Just add `!important` in css

```
function heightmod(value)
{
  $('.fc-time-grid .fc-slats td').css('height', value+'px !important');
}
```